# How to add a translation to an existing node/entity using REST?

Tags: 8

I have a headless Drupal 8 and want to create a translation for an existing NODE using a POST request but cannot figure how to.

I know how to create, edit and delete a node but am unsure on how to add a translation to an existing node. If I add the langcode it creates a new node in that specified language but I want a translation for an existing node ID.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load the node first and than addTranslation. You can check if exists or not. This way I was able to do it.

```
    $transNode = Node::load($nid);
    $transNode = $transNode->addTranslation("en");
    $transNode->title = $title_EN;
    $transNode->body= $body_EN;
    $transNode->field_1 = $field_1_EN;
    $transNode->save();
```

Comment: After a bit of more research. Your response is correct. REST does not support adding translations so I actually had to create a custom endpoint, load the node and add a translation using a variation of the above code.